# Django middleware with login and password which hides all the website pages

Tags: python, django, middleware

I have written following middleware which renders form and asks user for login and password. The middleware should be applied to the whole website:

```
class InviteLoginForWebsiteMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.session.get('has_invite') == True:
            return None

        form = WebsiteLoginForm()
        extra_context = dict()
        extra_context['form'] = form
        template_name = 'websiteLogin.html'

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = WebsiteLoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                login = form.cleaned_data['login']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                if login == "mylogin" and password == "mypassword":
                    request.session['has_inv'] = True
                    return None

        return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name, extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

The problem with this solution is that when I am creating the form inside *process_request* csrf token is missing on the rendered page. I have looked for the answer and found that developers recommend to generate form and process it inside *process_view*

After moving all the code into *process_view* like:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if request.session.get('has_inv') == True:
        return None

    form = WebsiteLoginForm()
    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['form'] = form
    template_name = 'websiteLogin.html'

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WebsiteLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login = form.cleaned_data['login']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            if login == "mylogin" and password == "mypassword":
                request.session['has_inv'] = True
                return None

    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name, extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

the code started to work, csrf token was generated and I was able to submit form with login and password.

The problem appears when user enters not valid page like *www.mysite.com/notworkingurl/*. In this case the *process_view* is not working, 404 error raised and user is redirected to page which shows partly the interface of the web app. And, of course, I expect that middleware should hide all the pages of the app.

**Once again:**

1. When I place the code inside *process_request* I can catch any call
   to any page on the website, but csrf is not rendered. As result csrf error raised when user submits form.
2. When I place
       the code inside *process_view* everything is working for the page in
       case it exists. If it doesn't exist user is redirected according to
       404 and other exception urls. And I don't want this redirect to happen.

Can someone suggest any good way to solve this issue?

**Solution:**

Thanks to suggestion of @knbk one of possible solutions is to use csrf_protect decorator. To make this idea work I have modified my view class as follows:

```
class ExtraContextTemplateViewCsrfProtect(TemplateView):
  extra_context = None

  @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ExtraContextTemplateViewCsrfProtect, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ExtraContextTemplateViewCsrfProtect, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.extra_context:
      context.update(self.extra_context)
    return context

  post = TemplateView.get
```

Comment: Do you redirect 404 requests to `process_view`?

Comment: no, I have custom urls which redirect to 404 views when 404 exception is raised. When my middleware code is working inside "process_view" and user enters not correct url, the end view does not exist and 404 is raised.

Comment: That's odd. Which line of `process_view` raises 404 exception?

Comment: I edited my previous answer. Have a look, please!

Comment: the process_view which are shown doesn't raise any exception but again when user enters not correct url then it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware is not just missing a csrf token, *it's vulnerable to CSRF attacks*.

If you want to use this pattern, rather than redirecting to a single login view, you should move all the form logic into the actual view. You can then use `csrf_protect` to protect the view against CSRF attacks, which also enables you to use the token in the template:

```
class InviteLoginForWebsiteMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.session.get('has_invite') == True:
            return None

        return csrf_protect(CustomLoginView.as_view())(request)
```

However, I would recommend the method suggested by matox.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will be very vulnerable to attacks but in my case it will be okay, because, as I wrote to matox, it will be only add hoc solution to hide the website for the first time with ability to switch it on or off time-to-time. If to use your code directly then it is not working, but if to modify it and move csrf_protect inside of my TemplateView then it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to play with login required middleware:

[Django Login Required Middleware](http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware)

settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
 r'^about\.html$',
 r'^legal/', # allow any URL under /legal/*
) 

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'python.path.to.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
)
```

LoginRequiredMiddleware:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from re import compile

EXEMPT_URLS = [compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [compile(expr) for expr in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    """
    Middleware that requires a user to be authenticated to view any page other
    than LOGIN_URL. Exemptions to this requirement can optionally be specified
    in settings via a list of regular expressions in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS (which
    you can copy from your urls.py).

    Requires authentication middleware and template context processors to be
    loaded. You'll get an error if they aren't.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user'), "The Login Required middleware\
 requires authentication middleware to be installed. Edit your\
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert\
 'django.contrib.auth.middlware.AuthenticationMiddleware'. If that doesn't\
 work, ensure your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting includes\
 'django.core.context_processors.auth'."
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
            if not any(m.match(path) for m in EXEMPT_URLS):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using it in my app as well. But if I will play with it then I have to open at least possibility to create accounts in my app. And it is not what I want. I am looking for some kind of add hoc solution which can be easily switched on or off when required.

Comment: You can easily switch it off by commenting out the middleware in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: yes, that is true, as well, as any other middleware

Comment: And you can replace `request.user` with your own condition. This function is just going to redirect any unauthorized requests to your login page. I believe this is what you essentially need.

Comment: the problem here is that I have to give access to accounts functionality, so basically, users should be able to create profiles, modify them and so on. This functionality is already presented in the website but I don't want to refactor the code. Simple wrapper around the whole app will fit better in this case. At the same time you solution is more prefessional and robust.